# jquery dataTables multiple page with functionality not working right with jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Context:**

I am using the dataTables jquery library with my asp.net mvc model view. I have an item model containing a list of department models in it. I have a Html.EditorFor() to display the list of department models in the dataTables table.

**Problem**

Each row has a checkbox that has a click function that will delete the row through an ajax post request. 
It works great on the first page of datas. But on the other pages, the click emitter isnt set up and thus the ajax request doesn't fire. It only works for the first page of rows on the dataTables UI.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: a jsfiddle would be great for this

Comment: Could you show us how you add this "click" listener to your checkboxes? :)

Comment: Found a solution, redundant but works. I added a click handler to the <a> tags (Next, Prev) which will add in the click handler for the checkboxes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach click event handler with jquery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Because after paging dataTables reload the tableBody and all attached event handler, which are not attached for live mode, will be lost. Something like this..

```
$("#dataTableWrapper").on("click", "td", function(event){ 
   // your code 
});
```

Comment: This should work indeed. That why I asked him to show us how he attaches the listener to the click event as he may already have the "on" event listener...

Comment: thanks yeah that worked. i wanted to add the code into this issue but it wouldnt let me edit what i wrote.